# Remove background image which is important by Default

Tags: html, css, background-image, styling

Actually, I'm using a toaster library, and everything is working fine. My issue is that the toaster is automatically grabbing an important background image. And since the background image must be removed, I am unable to do it myself. Now what should I do? Is there another option or way to get rid of the !important tag that comes with background images by default?

As you can see `class="toast-error"` is taking the default bg with `!important`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has Id, Class, and Important, so to remove it you need a stronger selector

a) Id + Class + Important + Userstyle: userstyles (from extenstions) are more important then in-page css

b) Id + Id + Important: add an extra id that is already in the page, like `#polotno-whatever ~ #toast-container > .toast-error`

c) Inline + Important: in case you have acess to JS or HTML and thus can change element.style attribute. You'll need MutationObserver to check when new elements are added in realtime

d) Id + Class + Important + Later: generally, if the exactly same selector, and the style tag is later then that one it'll override

Comment: I tried the point b. And it works. You rock man